# Is it possible to create custom annotations with field (dependsOn) that is a class which is annotated with another custom annotation

Tags: java, annotations

is it possible to create in Java a custom annotation that would have a field that would accept class that only is annotated with another custom annotation?

Example:

**Main Annotation**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface MainCustomAnnotation {
}
```

and ***related Annotation***

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface RelatedAnnotation {
    public (needed type here) dependsOn();
}
```

So I can do this

```
@MainAnnotation
public class MainAnnotatedClass {
}
```

```
@RelatedAnnotation(dependsOn=MainAnnotation.class)  <---- Whatever needed here
public class DependantClass {
}
```

So that like this *DependantClass* would always depend on a class that has the *MainAnnotation* Annotation?

Comment: You can define your custom annotation with many attributes, you can check Hibernate Validator for custom annotation. You can also develop in plain java without using any third party library. What is the actual problem ?

Comment: Thank you for the response :) The problem is that I need to say that the custom annotation attribute must be of type a class that is annotated with the other custom annotation. A.k.a. @Annotation(dependsOn = SomeClassAnnotatedWithMainAnnotation.class)